# How to convert RGB images to grayscale in PyTorch dataloader?

Tags: python, pytorch

I've downloaded some sample images from the MNIST dataset in `.jpg` format. Now I'm loading those images for testing my pre-trained model.

```
# transforms to apply to the data
trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])

# MNIST dataset
test_dataset = dataset.ImageFolder(root=DATA_PATH, transform=trans)

# Data loader
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
```

Here `DATA_PATH` contains a subfolder with the sample image.

Here's my network definition

```
# Convolutional neural network (two convolutional layers)
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.network2D = nn.Sequential(
           nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
           nn.ReLU(),
           nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
           nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
           nn.ReLU(),
           nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.network1D = nn.Sequential(
           nn.Dropout(),
           nn.Linear(7 * 7 * 64, 1000),
           nn.Linear(1000, 10))

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.network2D(x)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.network1D(out)
        return out
```

And this is my inference part

```
# Test the model
model = torch.load("mnist_weights_5.pth.tar")
model.eval()

for images, labels in test_loader:
   outputs = model(images.cuda())
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 5, 5], expected input[1, 3, 28, 28] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead
```

I understand that the images are getting loaded as 3 channels (RGB). So how do I convert them to single channel in the `dataloader`?

Update:
I changed `transforms` to include `Grayscale` option

```
trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,)), transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1)])
```

But now I get this error

```
TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found an extremely simple solution to this problem. The required dimensions of the tensor are `[1,1,28,28]` whereas the input tensor is of the form `[1,3,28,28]`. So I need to read just 1 channel from it

```
images = images[:,0,:,:]
```

This gives me a tensor of the form `[1,28,28]`. Now I need to convert this to a tensor of the form `[1,1,28,28]`. Which can be done like this

```
images = images.unsqueeze(0)
```

So putting the above two lines together, the prediction part of the code can be written like this

```
for images, labels in test_loader:
   images = images[:,0,:,:].unsqueeze(0) ## Extract single channel and reshape the tensor
   outputs = model(images.cuda())
```

Comment: the only point that you just take information from one red channel, which is not precise.

Comment: No, this might actually work if R=G=B. In that case there is no reason to convert, you can just slice one channel. I am however, worried about how pytorch converts the grayscale image to RGB, which may not be simply copy grayscale channel to R and G and B. The default pytorch loader is: `def pil_loader(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        img = Image.open(f)
        return img.convert('RGB')`

Answer (score 13):

When using `ImageFolder` class and with no custom loader, pytorch uses PIL to load image and converts it to RGB. Default Loader if torchvision image backend is PIL:

```
def pil_loader(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        img = Image.open(f)
        return img.convert('RGB')
```

You can use **torchvision's  Grayscale** function in transforms. It will convert the 3 channel RGB image into 1 channel grayscale. Find out more about this at [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Grayscale)

A sample code is below,

```
import torchvision as tv
import numpy as np
import torch.utils.data as data
dataDir         = 'D:\\general\\ML_DL\\datasets\\CIFAR'
trainTransform  = tv.transforms.Compose([tv.transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
                                    tv.transforms.ToTensor(), 
                                    tv.transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
trainSet        = tv.datasets.CIFAR10(dataDir, train=True, download=False, transform=trainTransform)
dataloader      = data.DataLoader(trainSet, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
images, labels  = iter(dataloader).next()
print (images.size())
```

Comment: I get the following error with your code:
`RuntimeError: output with shape [1, 32, 32] doesn't match the broadcast shape [3, 32, 32]`

Comment: this error was resolved implementing this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124407/output-and-broadcast-shape-mismatch-in-mnist-torchvision

Comment: i dont think this converts the image to grayscale because your either using Red or Green or Blue sections of the image and none are grayscale

Answer (score 1):

You may implement Dataloader not from ImageFolder, but from Datagenerator, directly load images in `__getitem__` function. PIL.Image.open("..") then grayscale, to numpy and to Tensor.

Another option is to calculate greyscale(Y) channel from RGB by formula `Y = 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B.`
 Slice array and convert to one channel.

But how do you train your model? usually train and test data loads in same way.